# Nested mapping of object using annotations in Mybatis

Tags: java, orm, mybatis

I have a POJO like this

```
 public class Application
{
  private String dcn;
  private Party applicant;
  private Date createdDateTime;
  private NamedValue[] flags;
  // containing getter and setters
  }
public class Party
{
  private String lastName;
  private String rfc;
  // containing getter and setters..
  }
```

And my table columns are..

```
dcn,applicantLastName,applicantRFC,createdDateTime,flag
```

all are varchar type.
 I am using annotations to get data from the above table and set it to POJO using below Query.

```
@Select("SELECT dcn,applicantLastName,applicantRFC,createdDateTime,flag FROM DnA_Application WHERE dcn=#{dcn}")
  List<Application> getByProc(int proc);
```

I am not getting data for Party bean from table using above config .Please help.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to map the result of the join using annotations. This is not supported in mybatis. Here's a quotation from the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html#Mapper_Annotations):

> You will notice that join mapping is not supported via the Annotations
>   API. This is due to the limitation in Java Annotations that does not
>   allow for circular references

One way to do mapping is to define a result map in the xml and reference it via `@ResultMap`.

mapper.xml:

```
<resultMap id="ApplicationResultMap" type="Application" autoMapping="true">
   <id property="dcn" column="dcn"  />
   <association property="party" javaType="Party" resultMap="PartyResultMap" columnPrefix="applicant"/>
</resultMap>
```

In mapper interface:

```
@Select("SELECT dcn,applicantLastName,applicantRFC,createdDateTime,flag FROM DnA_Application WHERE dcn=#{dcn}")
@ResultMap("ApplicationResultMap")
List<Application> getByProc(int proc);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reponse .

Comment: @AtulSingh, if this answer solves your problem you should formally accept it: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers